# System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.' using files from the embedded resources

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a Resource File; that I've embedded into the Resources. It is a Certificate. Simply put, I am trying to call the file to be able then install the certificate; without the user having to download the file. Here is my running code:

```
        public static void TESTNEWINSTALL()
    {
        string myString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.FiddlerRoot);
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        store.Add(new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(myString)));
        store.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
```

The Embedded Resource is called **FiddlerRoot** but it's actually a file named FiddlerRoot.cer. However I am getting an error code: Illegal characters in path on the line:
**store.Add(new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(myString)));**

I also have attached a photo for additional explanation. What am I doing wrong here?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/26aiF.png

Comment: What does the debugger say the value of `myString` is.

Comment: Yeah, what's the path? Not every character is valid in a path on Windows, after all.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel It's an embedded byte array, it doesn't have a path.

Comment: There's no such thing as *"files from the embedded resources"*. Resources are resources and files are files. The whole point of using resources is to not use files. If you're going to call a method that specifically requires a file, you have to provide a file, not a resource. You can extract a resource and save the data to a file and then use that, although it may be seen as virus-like behaviour under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateFromCertFile` expects a filename, not an actual certificate.

Furthermore:

- You are for some reason creating a second certificate from the first, for no apparent reason.
- You are reading the certificate data as a string, which is not necessary, and in the case of DER encoding is counter-productive (it's not necessarily a valid string).
- You are also missing various `using`s.

```cs
public static void TESTNEWINSTALL()
{
    var certData = Properties.Resources.FiddlerRoot;
    using X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    using var cert = new X509Certificate2(certData);
    store.Add(cert);
    store.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```